# Execute "switch-to-buffer" while in dired mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following in my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key "\M-s" 'switch-to-buffer)
```

However, when i am in dired mode "viewing a directory" M-s doesnt execute "switch-to-buffer" instead it shows M-s waiting on more input.

How is it possible to have switch-to-buffer work while in dired mode?

Comment: On a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk, here are the dired keymap assignments: ;; isearch; `(define-key map (kbd "M-s a C-s")   'dired-do-isearch)`; `(define-key map (kbd "M-s a M-C-s") 'dired-do-isearch-regexp)`; `(define-key map (kbd "M-s f C-s")   'dired-isearch-filenames)`; `(define-key map (kbd "M-s f M-C-s") 'dired-isearch-filenames-regexp)`.  So you would need to set those `dired-mode-map` assignments to `nil` or something else, or redefine your keyboard shortcut for `switch-to-buffer`.

Comment: `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-s s") 'switch-to-buffer)`

Comment: I get:
Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map

Comment: This however worked:
(eval-after-load "dired-x"
  '(progn
     ;; Add an alternative local binding for the command
     ;; bound to M-o
     ;; Unbind M-o from the local keymap
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-s") nil)))

Comment: The Emacs Trunk bindings I cited from are in `dired.el`.  So there are a few common methods to accomplish what you did -- e.g., `(require 'dired)` before using `(define-key dired-mode-map . . .)`; `(eval-after-load "dired" . . .)`; `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () . . . ))`; and what you did also works because `dired-x` requires dired.

Answer (score 2):

`M-s` is an Isearch prefix key now.  In Dired mode, you have these bindings by default (try `M-s C-h` from `emacs -Q'):

```
Major Mode Bindings Starting With M-s:
key             binding
---             -------

M-s a       Prefix Command
M-s f       Prefix Command

M-s f C-s   dired-isearch-filenames
M-s f ESC   Prefix Command

M-s a C-s   dired-do-isearch
M-s a ESC   Prefix Command

M-s f C-M-s dired-isearch-filenames-regexp

M-s a C-M-s dired-do-isearch-regexp



Global Bindings Starting With M-s:
key             binding
---             -------

M-s .       isearch-forward-symbol-at-point
M-s _       isearch-forward-symbol
M-s h       Prefix Command
M-s o       occur
M-s w       isearch-forward-word

M-s h .     highlight-symbol-at-point
M-s h f     hi-lock-find-patterns
M-s h l     highlight-lines-matching-regexp
M-s h p     highlight-phrase
M-s h r     highlight-regexp
M-s h u     unhighlight-regexp
M-s h w     hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns
```

So your choice of binding `M-s` to something different is not a great choice, for Dired mode and in general.  You can do it, but then you either have to define a different Isearch prefix key or do without having Isearch commands on a prefix key.

Remember that when Emacs seems to be waiting for more keys you probably typed a prefix key.  And remember that you can (usually) type a prefix key and then hit `C-h` to see the keys that have that prefix.

If you use library [help-fns+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can use `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`) to get a human-readable listing of all of the (non-menu) keys defined for a given keymap that is bound to a variable.  In this case, `C-h M-k dired-mode-map` shows you all of the keys in that keymap.